# Ifstream is not working

Tags: c++, utf-8

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "Gyvūnas.h"
#include "Maistas.h"
using namespace std;

//-------------------------------------------------------
const char CFm[] = "Maistas.txt";
const char CFg[] = "Gyvūnai.txt";
const int CMax   = 100;
//-------------------------------------------------------

//--------------------------------------------------------
void Skaityti  (const char CFm[], Maistas M[], int & n);
void Skaityti2 (Gyvūnas G[], int & kg);
//----------------------------------------------------------
int main(){
    setlocale (LC_ALL , "Lithuanian");
    Maistas M[CMax];
    Gyvūnas G[CMax];
    int n;
    int kg;
    Skaityti  (CFm, M, n);
    Skaityti2 (G, kg);
    cout << M[1].ImtiMetus() << " " << n << endl;
    system ("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
//----------------------------------------------------------
void Skaityti (const char CFm[], Maistas M[], int & n)
{
    string produktas;
    double kiekis;
    int metai;
    int mėnuo;
    int diena;
    ifstream fd(CFm);
    fd >> n;
    for (int i = 0 ; i<=n ; i++){ 
        fd >> produktas >> kiekis >> metai >> mėnuo >> diena;
        M[i].Dėti(produktas, kiekis, metai, mėnuo, diena);
    }
    fd.clear ();
    fd.close();
}
void Skaityti2 (Gyvūnas G[], int & kg)
{
    int narvas;
    string pavadinimas;
    int skaičius;
    int produktas;
    int kiekis;
    int n;
    ifstream fd(CFg);
    fd >> n;
    for (int i = 0 ; i<=kg ; i++){
        fd >> narvas >> pavadinimas >> skaičius >> produktas >> kiekis;
        G[i].Dėti(narvas, pavadinimas, skaičius, produktas, kiekis);
    }
    kg = n;
    fd.close();
}
```

When I set breakpoints it shows that in this part ifstream cannot read variable n from file:

```
 ifstream fd(CFm);
    fd >> n;
    for (int i = 0 ; i<=n ; i++){ 
        fd >> produktas >> kiekis >> metai >> mėnuo >> diena;
        M[i].Dėti(produktas, kiekis, metai, mėnuo, diena);
    }
    fd.clear ();
    fd.close();
```

Errors are:

> std::basic_ios
>
> Filebuffer {_Set_eback=0xcccccccc  _Set_egptr=0xcccccccc  ...}   std::basic_filebuf >

Comment: What's the content of the file? Try to read a line using `std::string s; if (std::getline(fd, s)) { std::cout << "read='" << s << "'\n"; } else { std::cout << "failed to read anything\n"; }` This should give an indication on what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

What you have are not errors, just values of the pointers. It seems that you can't open `CFm` file. Please confirm if you really have `Maistas.txt` in the working directory (for test, you could just move it to C:\Maistas.txt and then pass `"C:\\Maistas.txt"` as absolute file path.

Also, there's a way to check if the `ifstream` is properly opened - you can do that by checking `failbit`:

```
ifstream fd(CFm);
if(!fd.good())
{
   cerr << "Could not open the file!" << endl;
   return;
}
```

Comment: I have already tried to do failbit checking and it showed that file is opening correctly. The problem still remains while trying to read n.

Answer (score 0):

Try rename `Gyvūnai.txt` to `Gyvunai.txt`.
Using non-ascii symbols as variable-names and function-names is bad practice (`Dėti`,`skaičius`), though Visual Studio allow this, using string literals with non-ascii symbols is even worse - actual char code will depend on encoding of source file and compiler code-page settings. Compiler can treat sources as CP1251 when it's actually UTF-8 and have two chars for `ū`.