# Error opening a file in C++: Error getting characters from string

Tags: c++, string, file, io

So I have some code for opening a file:

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

void OpenFile(std::string filename);

int main()
{
    OpenFile("c:\\Programming\\Viper\\ViperEngine\\Debug\\plop.png");

    return 0;
}

void OpenFile(std::string filename)
{
    std::ifstream file(filename, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);

    if(!file.good())
    {
        std::cout << "I am Error";
        std::cin.get();

        return;
    }

    std::cin.ignore();

    file.close();
}
```

This all looks well and good to me, except that it doesn't work.  When I run the Debugger, it says that Seteback and setegptr are equal to 0xcccccccc and that there are errors reading the characters from the string, when trying to open the file.  I tried just hard-coding the filename into the file open call (std::ifstream texFile("c:\Programming\Viper\ViperEngine\Debug\floop.png", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary)), but that still did not work.  The strange thing is it works fine if I use a file called "bloop.bmp" in exactly the same directory.  I am at a loss.  I had a look around on Google, where it said things about the string perhaps being destroyed before it could be used, but the string is still fine at the file-opening line.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eI4gh.png) is a screenshot of the Debug watches.

I can continue with my little project for a while with this problem, but it's mighty annoying, so any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT: Now with a minimal reproducible code, and Debug watch at the correct stage.  Thanks for the tips, guys.

Comment: Post a [MCVE] please.

Comment: OK, thanks, I'll put one together.

Comment: Does that code even *compile*? You're not passing enough argument to the function when you call it.

Comment: please check links, hope it gives some pointers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897449/ifstream-is-not-working http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20871996/error-opening-file-when-debugging

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I have edited the code with a minimal reproduceable example.  I have compiled it and run it and confirmed that it does not work.

Comment: This isn't the problem, but the code doesn't need to call `file.close()`. The `ifstream` destructor will do that.

Comment: oh, that's interesting.  Good to know!

Comment: @Makcheese You are opening a file, what for? what are you trying to achieve? You say you have errors trying to read characters from the string, which string?

Answer (score 0):

The debug output is shown at the wrong stage. You need to look at the _texFile variable after the debugger has stepped over it. The image that you have posted indicates that the debugger had not yet executed the statement in question, so you are probably misled by that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make some simple test. Put some file in `C:\file.png`, make sure file exists and check if it opens. You can also try to check if file exists using some C++ function, (`ifstream` needs absolute path, I had similar error when I was opening file by relative path)

Comment: Aight, I tried it with a file placed directly in the C:\\ directory.  Still doesn't work.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.